# Help with URL and HTACCESS

Tags: htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a social engine 3 website, in my website all URLS can be changed(URL-REWRITING) through the SE-url settings automatically, but in my website their is one module which is custom coded, where I have to set its URL manually in htaccess file,

the url which I want to changes is this:

```
mysite.com/institutes_desc.php?id=19
```

I want this URL to be changed like

`mysite.com/institutes/intitute_name` or `mysite.com/institutes/intitute_id`

My htaccess file is this

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +Followsymlinks
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.* - [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*/images/(.*)$ /images/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*/uploads_user/(.*)$ /uploads_user/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /profile.php?user=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ /profile.php?user=$1$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/documentgroups/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /documentgroup.php?user=$1&documentgroup_id=$2&group_id=$3&title=$4 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/documentgroups/([0-9]+)/([^/]+)?$ /documentgroup.php?user=$1&documentgroup_id=$2$3 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/documents/([0-9]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /document.php?user=$1&document_id=$2&title=$3 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/documents/([0-9]+)/([^/]+)?$ /document.php?user=$1&document_id=$2$3 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/documents/?$ /documents.php?user=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/documents/?$ /documents.php?user=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^documents/tag/([^/]+)/?$ /browse_documents.php?tag=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^documents/category/([0-9]+)/?$ /browse_documents.php?i=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/blog/([0-9]+)/?$ /blog.php?user=$1&blogentry_id=$2 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/blog/([^/]+)?$ /blog.php?user=$1$2 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/blog/?$ /blog.php?user=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/trackback/([0-9]+)/?$ /blog_ajax.php?task=trackback&user=$1&blogentry_id=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/videos/([0-9]+)/?$ /video.php?user=$1&video_id=$2 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?group/([0-9]+)/([^/]*)$ /group.php?group_id=$1$2$3 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?group/([0-9]+)/album/([0-9]+)/([^/]*)$ /group_album_file.php?group_id=$2&groupmedia_id=$3$4 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?group/([0-9]+)/discussion/([0-9]+)/([^/]*)$ /group_discussion_view.php?group_id=$2&grouptopic_id=$3$4 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?group/([0-9]+)/discussion/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([^/]*)$ /group_discussion_view.php?group_id=$2&grouptopic_id=$3&grouppost_id=$4$5 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/articles/([^/]+)?$ /articles.php?user=$1$2 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/articles/?$ /articles.php?user=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^article/([0-9]+)(/[^/]*)?$ /article.php?article_id=$1&article_slug=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/job/([0-9]+)/?$ /job.php?user=$1&jobentry_id=$2 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/job/([^/]+)?$ /job.php?user=$1$2 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/job/?$ /job.php?user=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/trackback/([0-9]+)/?$ /job_ajax.php?task=trackback&user=$1&jobentry_id=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/classifieds/([0-9]+)/?$ /classified.php?user=$1&classified_id=$2 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/classifieds/([0-9]+)/([^/]+)?$ /classified.php?user=$1&classified_id=$2$3 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/classifieds/?$ /classifieds.php?user=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?event/([0-9]+)/([^/]*)$ /event.php?event_id=$1$2$3 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?event/([0-9]+)/album/([0-9]+)/([^/]*)$ /event_album_file.php?event_id=$2&eventmedia_id=$3$4 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^application/([0-9]+)/?$ /app.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Can anyone help me in this? how can I set my url this way?

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume that institute IDs have to be integers - no letters or decimal points or anything.

```
# Turn on URL re-writing
RewriteEngine On

# Clean URLs for institutes.
RewriteRule ^institutes/([0-9]+)/?$   /institutes_desc.php?id=$1    [NC,L]
```

For further information, I refer you to Dave Childs' [thorough introduction to URL rewriting](http://www.addedbytes.com/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/).

Comment: hey, this helped me, the urls are working now, but the problem is I have to manually put this URL in address bar and check, if I click the link, then still it shows the old URL, is their any htaccess rule, where automatically old URLS will be redirected to the new one?

Comment: @Niraj Chauhan Try a 301 redirect, using a regular expression to pull the ID.  Thus: `RedirectMatch 301 /institutes_desc.php?id=([0-9]+) http://mysite.com/institutes/$1` -- and note that the second bit MUST have the full URL of your site, starting with the HTTP.  EDIT: Oh, and if you can, it would be better to fix the links in the pages.  The 301 redirect will let old URLs still work, but it slows down page load a teeny bit because it adds an extra HTTP request (the redirect).

Comment: @NirajChauhan "if I click the link, then still it shows the old URL" - You still have to actually change the URL in your application. The rewrite above simply allows the new URL to work.